# How can i sort a List<string> according to the numbers in each string in each index?

Tags: c#, .net

In the end in threadList for example in index 0 i have:

`1. hello world`

Then in index 2 i have:

`33. hello`

Then in index 3 i have:

`76. hi`

In index 4:

`2. good`

The numbers `1 33 76 2` are part of the string in each index.

`1. hello world` is a string.
I want to sort the List according to the numbers so in this example it should be:

```
1. hello world
2. good
33. hello
76. hi
```

And again the numbers are part of the string they are not int.

This is the method that create the List:

```
public string GetResponsers(string contents)
        {
            string responser = "";
            List<string> threadList = new List<string>();
            int f = 0;
            int startPos = 0;
            while (true)
            {
                string firstTag = "<FONT CLASS='text16b'>";
                string lastTag = "&n";
                f = contents.IndexOf(firstTag, startPos);
                if (f == -1)
                {
                    break;
                }
                int g = contents.IndexOf(lastTag, f);
                startPos = g + lastTag.Length;
                responser = contents.Substring(f + 22, g - f - 22);

                threadList.Add(responser);
            }
            return responser;
        }
```

Comment: "The numbers 1 33 76 2 are part of the string in each index." where?..and also your example you say 1.helloworld 1.hi 1.hello where by what you say you need should be 1.helloworld 3.hello 2.good and so on...please clarify.

Comment: terrybozzio in the string variable responser the string there is a number with a text for example "1. hi" and this i add to the threadList. Now i want to sort the numbers with the text of each number but the numbers are part of the string. "1. hi"

Comment: in your sample code u just have 1 string -contents - and inside the method you build a list<string> but in your question you say that there are multiple strings and you need to oreder them.So even if you have a list with those strings and pass each one to this method you are instanciating a new list each time this is why is comfusing what is the original list and what you intend to be for the final result.

Comment: and i could have tried to guess what your intent is like the answers here,and probably(i hope) they are right but it wouldnt hurt to put more insight in the question.

Comment: The markdown formatting changed all the numbers in the question to `1.`. I fixed that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I see what you want...

```
yourList.OrderBy(str => {
    var match = Regex.Match(str, @"^([-+]?\d+)");
    return match.Success ? int.Parse(match.Groups[1].Value) : int.MaxValue;
});
```

This will return an `IEnumerable<string>` ordered by the value of the integer number that appears at the beginning of the string. Entries without a number will be put at the end.

---

EDIT: If you want the variable `yourList` to be ordered, then you have to reassign it:

```
yourList = yourList
    .OrderBy(str => {
        var match = Regex.Match(str, @"^([-+]?\d+)");
        return match.Success ? int.Parse(match.Groups[1].Value) : int.MaxValue;
    })
    .ToList();
```

Comment: I think a regex is overkill for what a .Sort() will do just as well in this case

Comment: @JohnathonSullinger A simple textual sort would put data like `2000.` before `24.` for instance, because `'0' < '4'`.

Comment: My mistake, forgot about that. Thanks for clearing that up for me

Comment: Lucas tried your solution what i get is: 1. then 4. then 15. then 2,3,6,5,7.....still not sorted good.

Comment: @SharonKasis This will not reorder the list in-place but return a new ordered sequence. See it working here: http://ideone.com/gy958R (and see my edit).

Answer (score 0):

If and i say again If the the examples in the list i will present to you are in the same format you have then you simply apply sort method which will sort automaticaly:

```
            List<string> lst = new List<string>()
            {
                "1. hello world",
                "76. hi",
                "33. hello",
                "2. good"
            };

            lst.Sort();//this will sort the list
```

After this the list will have the output you want.

EDIT:
As was pointed out(and very right indeed) i forgot about those cases where there was a 19 for example in this case apply the sort with a comparison:

```
     lst.Sort((s1, s2) =>
     {
          string first = new string(s1.TakeWhile(c => char.IsDigit(c)).ToArray());
          string second = new string(s2.TakeWhile(c => char.IsDigit(c)).ToArray());
          return int.Parse(first).CompareTo(int.Parse(second));
     });
```

Comment: this would probably sort `19` before `2` if exists and so on.

Comment: Since 2 people pointed it out, here's a proof it doesn't work quite right: http://ideone.com/IHBoGS

Comment: @pushpraj fixed thnx :) forgot about that "little problem".

Answer (score 0):

I think you could also try something like this:

```
yourList.OrderBy(s => {
    int num;
    var parts = string.Split(s, '.');
    if (parts.Count > 0 && int.TryParse(parts[0], out num))
        return num;

    return int.MaxValue;
});
```

In this way, you'll ensure a numeric sort of the numeric portion of the string without using a regular expression.

Comment: Since `int.TryParse` will reset `num` to `0` if it can't parse the string, this could be better: `return parts.Count > 0 && int.TryParse(parts[0], out num) ? num : int.MaxValue;`;

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski Good catch. I'll update the answer. Thanks! Funny thing is, that's what I was  going to write and decided otherwise....hehe.

Answer (score 0):

If you're on Windows 7 or greater, it has a [CompareStringEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd317761.aspx) function you could P/Invoke into. Its `SORT_DIGITSASNUMBERS` option does exactly what you want:

```
    static int CompareCSEx(string x, string y)
    {
        return CompareStringEx("", SORT_DIGITSASNUMBERS, x, x.Length,
                               y, y.Length, null, null, IntPtr.Zero) - 2;
    }

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true)]
    static extern int CompareStringEx(String strLocale, uint flags,
                                      String str1, int count1, string str2,
                                      int count2, string version,
                                      string reserved, IntPtr param);

    const int SORT_DIGITSASNUMBERS = 8;
```

Note this will treat *all* digits in the string as numbers, not just the digits at the start of the string.

And now dumb benchmark showing it running nearly 4x faster than fourpastmidnight's solution:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Random r = new Random(0);

    string[] values = (from i in Enumerable.Range(1, 500)
                        let order = r.Next()
                        orderby order
                        select i.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
                                    + ". " + RandomString(r)).ToArray();

    string[] fpmValues = values.ToArray();
    string[] csexValues = values.ToArray();

    Benchmark("FPM ", () => Array.Sort(fpmValues,
        new Comparison<string>(CompareFpm)));

    Benchmark("CSEX", () => Array.Sort(csexValues,
        new Comparison<string>(CompareCSEx)));

    Console.WriteLine("Sort equal: {0}",
        Enumerable.SequenceEqual(fpmValues, csexValues));
}

static string RandomString(Random r)
{
    int len = r.Next(1, 32);
    char[] buf = new char[len];

    for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i)
    {
        buf[i] = (char)r.Next('A', 'Z');
    }

    return new string(buf);
}

static int CompareFpm(string x, string y)
{
    int xi, yi;

    var parts = x.Split('.');
    if(parts.Length == 0 || !int.TryParse(parts[0], out xi))
    {
        xi = int.MaxValue;
    }

    parts = y.Split('.');
    if (parts.Length == 0 || !int.TryParse(parts[0], out yi))
    {
        yi = int.MaxValue;
    }

    return xi - yi;
}

static void Benchmark(string name, Action a)
{
    long start = Stopwatch.GetTimestamp(), end;
    long runs = 0;

    do
    {
        a();
        ++runs;
        end = Stopwatch.GetTimestamp();
    }
    while ((end - start) < (Stopwatch.Frequency * 5));

    Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1} runs/sec", name, runs / 5);
}
```

With output:

```
FPM : 681 runs/sec
CSEX: 2577 runs/sec
Sort equal: True
```

Comment: PInvoke is way too much overhead for such a simple thing. You'll spend more time marshalling between managed/unmanaged code than actually accomplishing any work.

Comment: What makes you think that?

Comment: @fourpastmidnight, here's a benchmark for you. P/Invoke can be very very fast if .NET doesn't have to marshal anything. Please don't downvote answers that satisfy the requirements of the question.

Comment: Unless the OP needs the actual string contents (after the initial number) sorted by string and numerically, PInvoke is still overkill. I reversed the vote because your solution works. But if you don't need the raw speed, then ditch the complexity of PInvoke (admittedly, this usage is not extremely complex--thankfully, no memory management/manual marshalling is needed).

Comment: And, unless you're calling the `Marshal.GetLastError` method, you should set `SetLastError = false` in your `DllImportAttribute`  declaration; see [this blog post by Brad Abrams](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brada/archive/2003/07/11/50135.aspx).

Comment: make that `Marshal.GetLastWin32Error` -- forgot the 'Win32' part.